# How to flash/blink scroll indicators in WatchKit for a WKInterfaceGroup

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I have a WatchKit app and on one view I want to indicate the user they can scroll vertically. My UI elements are placed in a vertical WKInterfaceGroup.

Now I want to indicate the users they can scroll by flashing or blinking the scroll indicator. Apple does this for example in the Workout app of the watch, after you finished a workout.

On UIKit you can do this on a scroll view, but is there an equivalent for WatchKit?